# Extract field from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, redips.drag

I have a JSON file that I want to extract a field from.

```
{
"player": [
    {
        "Position": "TEST",
        "Name": "TEST",
        "Squad_No": "TEST",
        "Club": "TEST",
        "Age": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "Position": "",
        "Name": "",
        "Squad_No": "",
        "Club": "",
        "Age": ""
    },
    ]
    }
```

I would like to take the "Name:" field and put it into a file with this format:

```
[["TEST",0,0,"","TEST"],["ns1.0a",1,0,"","ns1.0a"],
["ns1.1b",2,0,"","ns1.1b"],["ns1.2",3,0,"","ns1.2"]]
```

The aim is to load this file into a table using the [Redips](https://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/) load functionality.

Any ideas on the best method to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From where will value `ns1.1b` come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`

```
arr = arr.player.map( (s,i) => ( [ s.Name , i, 0, "" , s.Name ] ) );
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Along with @Bougarfaoui El houcine answer below. Just needed to use JSON.stringfy when writing to file. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the file you can do as @gurvinder372 said :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile('file', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  data = data.player.map( (s,i) => ( [ s.Name , i, 0, "" , s.Name ] ) );
  console.log(data);
});
```